# This commands should produce no [output]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Some Questions tagged [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output) are really about [io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io) (or more specifically, about [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io); check especially [those tagged [input][output]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input+output)... over 200 of them). But some use the tag only because the word exists somewhere in the Question.